# How to pass/call parameters (values) from Function to 'Select' stmt in SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have a problem passing parameters from function that I created into SQL*Plus 'Select' statement in the 'Where' clause. However, it seems that whatever syntax I utilized is either incorrect or not to use at all in this 'Where' clause situation.

Here is my function I created and it looks OK being compiled and ran good:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FXN(p_client_code      VARCHAR2
                                                   ,p_bill_seq         VARCHAR2
                                                   ,p_bill_control_seq VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  v_external_id      VARCHAR2(30);
  v_client_code      VARCHAR2(4) := p_client_code;
  v_bill_seq         NUMBER := to_number(p_bill_seq);
  v_bill_control_seq NUMBER := to_number(p_bill_control_seq);
  v_cnt              NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_cnt
  FROM BillControl@SQL_SAREP bc
  WHERE bc."ExternalID" IS NOT NULL
        AND bc."ExternalID" != ''
        AND bc."ClientCode" = p_client_code
        AND bc."BillControlSeq" = v_bill_control_seq
        AND bc."BillSeq" = v_bill_seq;
  IF v_cnt = 1 THEN
    SELECT bc."ExternalID"
    INTO v_external_id
    FROM BillControl@SQL_SAREP bc
    WHERE bc."ExternalID" IS NOT NULL
          AND bc."ExternalID" != ''
          AND bc."ClientCode" = p_client_code
          AND bc."BillControlSeq" = v_bill_control_seq
          AND bc."BillSeq" = v_bill_seq;
  ELSE
    v_external_id := NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN v_external_id;
END SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX;
/
```

---

Also, when I used 'IN OUT' parameter in function it failed after running it.

Now, here is the 'Select' statement I'm having difficulty passing parameters with:

```
SELECT NVL(TRIM(eb.CASE_NUM_REEVALUATED), TRIM(eb.CASE_NUM_DUPLICATED)) CaseNumReev
      ,gnc.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ
FROM EPE_Bill eb NETWORK_CROSSWALK gnc
WHERE substr(eb.MIC_BILL_ID, 5, 4) = SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX(p_client_code)
      AND gnc.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ = SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX(p_bill_seq) 
      AND (to_number(substr(eb.MIC_BILL_ID, 10, 10), '9999999999') = SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX(p_bill_control_seq) 
GROUP BY CaseNumReev, gnc.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ;
```

For the last two days I was left myself thoroughly perflexed.
With that, I would really appreciate if you help me with issue.

Thanks again...

Comment: Your function takes 3 parameters (no defaults) and yet you are calling it with only 1, which is invalid.

Comment: What specific error are you getting?  Also you have a typo with your function name in your posted code. In your create, it's SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FXN, in your where clause it's SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX.

Comment: You also can't `group by` a column alias; you'd need to repeat the who `nvl` clause (or wrap it another select). You can't call a function with an `in out` parameter from normal SQL, as you've already discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below function,ALso i made assumption that since you are passing only one parameter the remaining must be NULL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FXN(p_client_code IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL                                               
                                               ,p_bill_seq     IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                                               ,p_bill_control_seq IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_external_id      VARCHAR2(4000);
v_client_code      VARCHAR2(4) := p_client_code;
v_bill_seq         NUMBER := to_number(p_bill_seq);
v_bill_control_seq NUMBER := to_number(p_bill_control_seq);
v_cnt              NUMBER;
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     INTO v_cnt
     FROM BillControl@SQL_SAREP bc
     WHERE bc."ExternalID" IS NOT NULL
     AND bc."ExternalID" != ''
     AND bc."ClientCode" = NVL(p_client_code,bc."ClientCode")
     AND bc."BillControlSeq" = NVL(v_bill_control_seq,bc."BillControlSeq")
     AND bc."BillSeq" = NVL(v_bill_seq,bc."BillSeq");
   IF v_cnt = 1 THEN
      SELECT bc."ExternalID"
      INTO v_external_id
      FROM BillControl@SQL_SAREP bc
      WHERE bc."ExternalID" IS NOT NULL
      AND bc."ExternalID" != ''
      AND bc."ClientCode" = NVL(p_client_code,bc."ClientCode")
      AND bc."BillControlSeq" = NVL(v_bill_control_seq,bc."BillControlSeq")
      AND bc."BillSeq" = NVL(v_bill_seq,bc."BillSeq");
  ELSE
     v_external_id := NULL;
  END IF;
       RETURN v_external_id;
END SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX;
/
```

And your SQL SHOULD BE

```
SELECT REC.CaseNumReev,REC.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ FROM
(
 SELECT NVL(TRIM(eb.CASE_NUM_REEVALUATED), TRIM(eb.CASE_NUM_DUPLICATED)) CaseNumReev
  ,gnc.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ AS BILL_CONTROL_SEQ
 FROM EPE_Bill eb ,NETWORK_CROSSWALK gnc
 WHERE substr(eb.MIC_BILL_ID, 5, 4) = SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX(p_client_code)
 AND gnc.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ = SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX(p_bill_seq) 
 AND (to_number(substr(eb.MIC_BILL_ID, 10, 10), '9999999999')     =SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FNX(p_bill_control_seq))rec    
GROUP BY REC.CaseNumReev,REC.BILL_CONTROL_SEQ
```

Comment: Thanks...I'll try everything function/sql

Comment: Tried thr recompiled the modified function successfully. Then I ran the sql, modified one with error: ORA-00904: "P_BILL_CONTROL_SEQ": invalid identifier. Any ideas?

Comment: I figered it out to use single quotes for ‘p_client_code’ in where clause. So, disregard the ORA-00904 error. Now, I have another error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "GNXSA.GNX_SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_ID", line 28 Any ideas regarding function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can u post the function GNXSA.GNX_SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_ID in your question

Comment: It is a typo and I was looking for something else...The proper fxn name in the error is - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "SA_BILL_CNTRL_EXTRNL_FXN". Thank u for noticing...